# Using a mutiple table query to display data on an editable continuous form in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, continuous-forms

I need to use a fairly complex multiple table query as the data-source for a continuous form, but have the form remain editable. All of the form fields that I need to edit are only linked to a single table but I still need to display information from the multi-table query in a few of the fields in a non-editable fashion. I have accomplished this using DLookUp in the Record source query for the "display only" fields, but the performance is abysmal since the database is split and the backed resides on a server with linked tables. If I accomplish the same thing simply by using SELECT for the query fields I need to display the performance is fine, but the entire form becomes un-editable.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this more efficiently would be greatly appreciated. I've linked pictures of the the form, the form design page, the query design pages, and I've pasted the relevant SQL below.

[Form Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1vl.png)
[Form Design Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNeTe.png)

**ITNQuery SQL:** [ITNQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYWVG.png)

```
SELECT itn.id, 
       itn.itnnumber, 
       itn.portfolio, 
       itn.topic, 
       itn.itndate, 
       itn.statusid, 
       itn.notes, 
       itn.delivereddate, 
       itn.leadlinguistid, 
       itn.teamid                              AS Expr1, 
       itn.newversionentry, 
       itn.previousitn, 
       itn.reviewinglinguistid, 
       itn.itnresponse, 
       itn.leadresponsecoordinatorid, 
       itn.datesenttoleadcoordinator, 
       itn.responsedeadline, 
       itn.priority, 
       itn.casemanagerid, 
       itn.responsecoordinator2id, 
       itn.datesenttocoordinator2, 
       itn.responsecoordinator3id, 
       itn.datesenttocoordinator3, 
       itn.responsecoordinator4id, 
       itn.datesenttocoordinator4, 
       itn.coordinatinglinguistid, 
       Iif([itn].[statusid] <> 9 
           AND [itn].[statusid] <> 10 
           AND [itn].[statusid] <> 19 
           AND [itn].[statusid] <> 20 
           AND [itn].[statusid] <> 28 
           AND [itn].[statusid] <> 30, Iif([itn].[delivereddate] > 0, 
       Datediff("d", [itn].[itndate], [itn].[delivereddate]), 
       Datediff("d", [itn].[itndate], Now()))) AS ITNAge, 
       itn.newversionentry, 
       itn.teamid, 
       statuslist.[display order], 
       itn.cooraspondanceid, 
       itn.documenttypeid, 
       Dlookup("ducumentabreviation", "associateditntextquery", 
       "currentitnid =" & [itn].[id])         AS AssocAbrev, 
       Dlookup("itnnumber", "associateditntextquery", 
       "currentitnid =" & [itn].[id]) 
                                               AS AssocNumber
```

**AssociatedITNTextQuery:** [AssociatedITNTextQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2xrJ.png)

```
SELECT associateditns.current_itn_id AS CurrentITNID, 
       associateditns.associated_itn_id, 
       associateddocstextquery1.maxofitndate, 
       documenttypes.ducumentabreviation, 
       itn.itnnumber, 
       itn.itndate 
FROM   (itn 
        INNER JOIN documenttypes 
                ON itn.documenttypeid = documenttypes.id) 
       INNER JOIN (associateditns 
                   INNER JOIN associateddocstextquery1 
                           ON associateditns.current_itn_id = 
                              associateddocstextquery1.current_itn_id) 
               ON itn.id = associateditns.associated_itn_id 
WHERE  ( ( ( itn.itndate ) IN ( associateddocstextquery1 ! maxofitndate ) ) 
         AND 
         ( ( associateddocstextquery1.current_itn_id ) = 
           associateditns ! current_itn_id ) );
```

**AssociatedITNTextQuery1:** [AssociatedITNTextQuery1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EiTA.png)

```
SELECT associateditns.current_itn_id, 
       Max(ITN_1.itndate) AS MaxOfITNDate 
FROM   itn AS ITN_1 
       INNER JOIN associateditns 
               ON ITN_1.id = associateditns.associated_itn_id 
GROUP  BY associateditns.current_itn_id;
```

Comment: Your problem are not the multiple tables, but the `GROUP BY` in the subquery. This turns the whole result read-only. If you can't do without that, my best advice would be to think about moving the backend to SQL Server Express, where you can use a **view** to achieve what you want.

Comment: Andre, Thanks so much for the insight! Is there an easy way to get rid of the GROUP BY? It seems Access forces you to use it for any SELECT Fields that are not in the aggregate DLookUp function.